# State Variables in a Bellman Equation

Tags: asset-pricing

Can anyone explain to me exactly what a state variable is in a Bellman equation??
$$ V(x,y)=max\space u(c)+\beta V(x',y')$$

In some models with capital savings it's the capital $k_t$ you walk into period $t$ in others where there are many future states its all aggregate $S$ in the past. In some models it's dividends $d_t$ of a stochastic asset. It's obviously relevant variables that influence your decision making but I can't seem to find a consistent way to be able to identify state equations in a lot of the problem I am solving.

Answer (score 2):

State variables are simply variables that matter for the value function, the variable on which the value function depends on if you want. Conceptually, you could think of a state vector containing *all* the variables and then removing the variables that don't matter from your state vector.

In practice, the state variables choice really depends on the problem you're trying to solve. For physicist it could be the position of an object, the atmospheric pressure or whatever. For economist it could be the wealth of an agent, the level of capital of a firm, etc. It could be anything.

If you're having hard time figuring out what could it be in your model, try to ask yourself question like : "On what does the decision that I'm trying to understand depend?" or "What could influence the choice of an agent in this economy?".

You can provide more details on the problem you're trying to solve if you want a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Louis's answer is good.

In my understanding, state variables ensure your problem can be stated as a Markov decision problem.

Think of a balloon landing control problem under fuel consumption constraint.
Position and fuel level are obviously state variables.
But Newton principle implies to take into account acceleration. It is often possible by integration of Newton principle, that only speed is needed.
In the end, your state variables are position, speed, acceleration and fuel level. Your control is the fuel injection to balloon's engine.